# Prove that if $a_n \to 1$ then $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \to 1$ if $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that if $a_n \to 1$ then $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \to 1$ if $n \to \infty$.

What could be the way to prove that in that case also $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: The title is misleading, and wrong, what if the series was converging to 4 , does that mean that square root of the series also converges to 4?

Comment: If $a_n$ converged to $1$, then $S\ne 1$, also, why did you put the tag solution-verification if you don't think you have the solution?

Comment: It seems like you've got a few misunderstandings about what is being asked. To be honest, sometimes this forum is unhelpful because people like to be quick to post "solutions"/answers without actually helping the poster of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused. The question has nothing to do with any series. It is  question about convergence of sequences.

For $n$ sufficiently large $\frac  12 \leq a_n \leq 2$ so $(\frac  12)^{1/n} \leq a_n^{1/n} \leq 2^{1/n}$. Use Squeeze Theorem and the fact that $x^{1/n} \to 1$ for any positive number $x$.

Comment: This doesn't address any of a number of misunderstandings exhibited by the original poster

Comment: @T_M OP is totally confused. My answer is for the first sentence in the question. There are no infinite series in the question as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes exactly. So your answer doesn't really help them it just shows off that you know how to answer it!

Answer (score 1):

The claim follows from

$$|\sqrt[n]x-1|\le|x-1|,$$ for all $n\ge1$, which you can use in an $\epsilon/\delta$ proof.

Answer (score 0):

One major misunderstanding that your question exhibits is a confusion between a sequence and a series. I think you need to straighten that out before you have a chance of understanding a solution to the problem.